# Call a class for Minecraft Recipes

Tags: java, minecraft

I am having a small issue calling a Class file into my main class

I want to have a separate class to contain all my recipes, but i need to call it up in the common class.

The Recipe is called Recipes.

How would i call that class to load? 
The functions loads on @PreInit

```
    @EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) { }
```

Should i change this to Init or @PostInit, as the blocks are all created in @PreInit and @Init is completely empty ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just instanciate this class and use as you want.

```
Recipes recipes = new Recipes();
```

in this case is not necessary a injection

you can still get it with the constructor like:

```
Class YourClass{
  //do what you need here, for example instanciate the class and execute something.
public YourClass(){

}
```

}

You can also create a static class if you prefer.